# SequenceReplace is incorrectly modifying the list when a pattern partially matches

Tags: replacement, sequence

(Below is a big simplification of my actual use-case which reproduces the problem with `SequenceReplace`. Please assume my use of `SequenceReplace` is necessary).

I have a list of symbols with subscripts and square brackets.
E.g.

```
{ Subscript[a,1][0], Subscript[b,0][2], Subscript[b,1][1], Subscript[c,2][0]] }
```

or better visually:

> [image]

I wish to modify the list such that neighbouring `b` symbols with the same subscript value are removed. I am attempting this using the pattern

```
SequenceReplace[mylist, {Subscript[b, i_][_], Subscript[b, i_][_]} :> Nothing]
```

though this incurs a strange error. When the subscripts *do* match, it removes them fine:

> [image]

but when they *don't* match, it undesirably puts them in their own sub-list!

> [image]

Here, the expected output was the unchanged `mylist`.

This seems like a strange and undocumented behaviour; is this a bug, or am I not understanding something?

I notice this only occurs when **both** subscripts and [args] in present in my pattern. For example, without the args (e.g. `Subscript[b,_], Subscript[b,_] :> Nothing`) this sublist behaviour does not occur.

Furthermore, this behaviour seems specific to `SequenceReplacement` and *not* my pattern, since the unnecessarily verbose use of `ReplaceAll` doesn't exhibit it!

[image]

Comment: It does seem like either a bug or something that should be explained in the documentation. It's probably worth reporting to Wolfram and seeing what they have to say.

Comment: This was indeed a bug, and I've been told it's patched in the current12.0 release

Comment: Two years, still not patched, and still biting me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why that happens, but here's a workaround:

```
list1 = {Subscript[a,1][0],Subscript[b,0][2],Subscript[b,1][1],Subscript[c,2][0]};
list2 = {Subscript[a,1][0],Subscript[b,0][2],Subscript[b,0][1],Subscript[c,2][0]};

SequenceReplace[list1, {PatternSequence[Subscript[b,i_][_], Subscript[b,i_][_]]} -> Nothing]
SequenceReplace[list2, {PatternSequence[Subscript[b,i_][_], Subscript[b,i_][_]]} -> Nothing]
```

> {Subscript[a, 1][0], Subscript[b, 0][2], Subscript[b, 1][1], 
>    Subscript[c, 2][0]}
>
> {Subscript[a, 1][0], Subscript[c, 2][0]}

Comment: Thanks very much! Miraculously, though my 'MWE' still shows this bug, my original use-case has suddenly started working (I *think* due to some other unrelated rules in `SequenceReplace`). I think I need to lie down